# MonoDroid: Iterate over the controls in an Activity?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In Activity.OnContentChanged, I would like to iterate over all of the controls to look get their Tags.

I assume it has something to do with base.Window.HasChildren, but I can't figure out how to actually get the children.

EDIT: ViewGroup, the base class for most layouts, has GetChildCount and GetChildAt. But I still can't figure out how to get from the Activity to that root-level layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var viewGroup = this.Window.DecorView as ViewGroup;
if(viewGroup != null){
for (int i = 0; i < view.ChildCount; i++)
{
    var control = view.GetChildAt(i);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign an ID to the root element of your layout and access it through that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity you could do something like:

```
var root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.Root);

for (int i = 0; i < root.ChildCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(root.GetChildAt(i).Id);
}
```